# Index a vector by a sparseVector

Tags: r

I'm using the `Matrix` package of `R`. I have a sparseVector

```
index.map <- sparseVector(x=1:3, i=c(10, 33, 50), length=50)
```

and some values to look up (an ordinary vector)

```
values <- runif(3)
```

Now I wish to extract elements of `values` going through `index.map` e.g.

```
values[index.map[33]] # should return values[2]
```

I get the error

> `Error in values[index.map[33]] : invalid subscript type 'S4'`

presumably because R does not know how to subset the numeric `values` by a `sparseVector`.
I can coerce `index.map` to an integer to do the lookup:

```
values[as(index.map[33], 'integer')] == values[2] # TRUE
```

but this is rather verbose for such a simple operation, and I've got to do the coercion every time I use `index.map` - I'm not sure how efficient this is.

**Is there a different way to do this indexing?** or is this the only option?

---

I thought perhaps converting `values` to a sparseVector might help, as perhaps the Matrix package would know how to subset a sparseVector by another sparseVector, but it does not:

```
as(values, 'sparseVector')[index.map[33]]
# Error in as(values, "sparseVector")[index.map[33]] : 
#   object of type 'S4' is not subsettable
```

---

**Update** `@x` (thanks @AleksandrVoitov!) doesn't seem to work all the time. For example

```
values[index.map[c(10, 10, 33)]@x]
```

is returning `values[c(1, 2, 1)]` rather than `values[c(1, 1, 2)]`, while using `as(.., 'integer')` on `index.map[c(10, 10, 33)]` works as expected. Perhaps `@x` is not meant to be a 'public' way to interact with a sparseVector?

Answer (score 1):

Try subseting with:

```
values[index.map[33]@x]
```

This would give you

```
values[2]=0.608075
```

Comment: ahhhh, excellent! Thanks. Despite having used R for many years now, I still don't properly understand S4...

Comment: True. The S4 is a bit unusual in daily life.

Comment: Oops, hang on. Solution doesn't always work. `values[index.map[c(10, 10, 33)]@x]` is returning `values[c(1, 2, 1)]` rather than `values[c(1, 1, 2)]`. `values[as(index.map[c(10, 10, 33)], 'integer')]` works as expected. Is `@x` "officially supported"?